# Static Data Masking does not appear in SSMS 18 preview 6

Tags: ssms, data-masking

I installed SSMS version 18 preview 6 and am using it with SQL Server 2017. I want to test the Static Data Masking feature, but the option does not appear.

Answer (score 4):

It was removed from the final version of SSMS 18. Interestingly, no explanation deemed necessary to be given as why it was taken out or will this feature be coming soon.

From [SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 18.0 released for general availability](http://msft.today/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-18-0-released-for-general-availability/) by Brad Groux:

> - **Removed static data masking (preview) feature** – While this feature was available in previous previews, it did not make it into the GA version of SSMS, unfortunately.